# How to restrict the RecyclerView items and by giving the view all options as in flipkart view all reviews option

Tags: android

Can anyone help me how to restrict the recyclerview items to a certain number.
This facility can be viewed in flipkart reviews option. I dont have any idea on this concept.

[image]

Comment: Usually, APIs have pagination, so you can pass how many items you need to fetch from DB. There will be some useful parameters like the page, limit, offset, etc. the same API will give you a figure about how many items there to be loaded.

Comment: You can set new page which shows all reviews